# download Gmail messages beween certain dates

Tags: gmail, download, pop3

I have a mail client which I use to download messages from my Gmail account. However, for one reason or another the download of some messages failed, and I have two gaps in particular - each of about a week or two, which I would like to download. In the settings I can select "download all messages" or "download messages that arrive from now on". How can I tell it to download all messages as of a certain date, or all messages inside certain date ranges?

Thanks,
Mala

**Edit:** my client is a POP email client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential workaround would be to first use the Gmail interface to search for all emails in those dates ranges and then create a temporary label to tag those emails with.

Then in your imap client you could navigate to the folder that corresponds to the new label and select download all messages.

It seems though like there's other issues that need to be investigated if the imap client won't download all your messages if you ask it to.

Comment: Thanks I hadn't thought of that. I'm using POP though... would this still work?

Comment: I am not sure how labels interact with POP access on gmail.